# best possible way to get given substring

Tags: c#, .net

lets say I have string in format as below:

```
[val1].[val2].[val3] ...
```

What is the best way to get the value from the last bracket set `[valx]` ?

so for given example

```
[val1].[val2].[val3]
```

the result would be  `val3`

Answer (score 4):

You have to define *best* first, best in terms of readability or cpu-cycles?

I assume this is efficient and readable enough:

```
string values = "[val1].[val2].[val3]";
string lastValue = values.Split('.').Last().Trim('[',']');
```

or with `Substring` which can be more efficient, but it's not as safe since you have to handle the case that's there no dot at all.

```
lastValue = values.Substring(values.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).Trim('[',']');
```

So you need to check this first:

```
int indexOflastDot = values.LastIndexOf('.');
if(indexOflastDot >= 0)
{
    lastValue = values.Substring(indexOflastDot + 1).Trim('[',']');
}
```

Comment: If there's no dot, `LastIndexOf` returns -1, which works fine, no?

Comment: @Rawling: I've already added that as comment, but now i've also shown how you can check it.

Comment: No, I mean, it's *OK* if there's no dot because you'll just end up calling `.Substring(0)`

Comment: @Rolling: good catch, i havnt noticed it. However, I would prefer readability and maintainability and use the if anyway. Its also not correct to take the whole string as last value if it doesn't contain any values, is it?

Comment: perhaps there will just be a check for a empty string :)

Comment: @sasjaq: an empty string has no value for example. My point is, you mostly need to handle special cases anyway so it adds nothing but complexity to shorten the code in this way. However, in this case it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick solution to your problem (so not structural),

I'd say:

```
var startIndex = input.LastIndexOf(".["); // getting the last
```

then using the [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
var value = input.Substring(startIndex + 2, input.Length - (startIndex - 2)); // 2 comes from the length of ".[".
```

then removing the "]" with [TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function

```
var value = value.TrimEnd(']');
```

But this is by all means **not** the only solution, and not structural to apply.. Just one of many answers to your problem.

Comment: +1, `Split` is not the most efficient way when you only need the last item.

Comment: some problem with this code: `SubString` should be `Substring`,  should use `startIndex+2` as the starting point, and `input.Length-(startIndex+2)` as the lenth of the substring, or use `startIndex=input.LastIndexOf(".[")+2`. And last: `TrimEnd(']')`

Comment: thx for pointing it out @Bolu ! Just did a quick write up from the top of my head, didn't have a compiler or ide nearby... I'll edit it, but in the future feel free to edit it yourself as well as StackOverflow suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you always need the last brace. I would do it like this:

```
string input = "[val1].[val2].[val3]";
string[] splittedInput = input.split('.');
string lastBraceSet = splittedInput[splittedInput.length-1];
string result = lastBraceSet.Substring(1, lastBraceSet.Length - 2);
```

Comment: ... and strip the []-marks from that: string result = lastBraceSet.Substring(1, lastBraceSet.Length - 2);

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to access the `valx`.
The easiest solution that comes in my mind is this one:

```
        public void Test()
        {
            var splitted = "[val1].[val2].[val3]".Split('.');
            var val3 = splitted[2];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
string[] myStrings = ("[val1].[val2].[val3]").Split('.');
```

Now you can access via index. For last you can use `myStrings[myStrings.length - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Providing, that *none* of val1...valN *contains* `'.', '[' or ']'` you can use a simple *Linq* code:

```
  String str = @"[val1].[val2].[val3]";
  String[] vals = str.Split('.').Select((x) => x.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']')).ToArray();
```

Or if all you want is *the last* value:

```
  String str = @"[val1].[val2].[val3]";
  String last = str.Split('.').Last().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
```

Comment: are you sure you will split with space? `str.Split(' ')`

Comment: @sasjaq: Thank you! There of course should be '.', I'm sorry for my mistyping

Answer (score 0):

```
    string str = "[val1].[val2].[val3]";
    string last = str.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
    string result = last.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input="[val1].[val2].[val3]";
int startpoint=input.LastIndexOf("[")+1;
string result=input.Substring(startpoint,input.Length-startpoint-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the below regex. One warning is that it won't work if there are unbalanced square brackets after the last pair of brackets. Most of the answers given suffer from that though.

```
string s = "[val1].[val2].[val3]"
string pattern = @"(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\][^\[\]]*$)"
Match m = Regex.Match(s, pattern)

string result;

if (m.Success)
{
    result = m.Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use regular expression, as they are the most clear from intention point of view:

```
string input = "[val1].[val2].[val3] ...";
string match = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[val\d+\]")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value)
                    .Last();
```

Comment: I've never found a regex to be more clear than a split, or a substring.

Comment: @sasjaq, @paqogomez, I'm quite surprised but your mileage may vary of course. I found searching for `val\d+` pattern and taking last match (which is what this code exactly tells at first glance) much more clear than interpreting combination of `Split`, `Trim`, `Last` etc.

Comment: I'll concede that *this* regular expression is simple enough to be clear enough.  However, in general, regex's can make for some very unhappy inheritors of your project.